# "Show Applications" dock does not populate

Tags: launcher, 21.04, dock

I just did a clean install of 21.04. The "Show Applications" button at bottom left does not populate with installed programs, not even the default utilities. The only programs shown are
Additional Drivers,
Aisle Riot Software,
Calendar,
Cheese,
Files,
Firefox,
Language Support,
and the full set of LibreOffice programs.

Terminal is not listed, although Ctr-t opens it. Ubuntu Software, Thunderbird, Rhythmbox, Help and Settings are not listed, though they appear as a favorites along the left side and open up fine when clicked. I added EasyTAG and pinned it as a favorite, but it's not shown in the Show Applications list.

Gnome tweaks says there are no gnome extensions active.

I have no idea how to even begin to troubleshoot this issue. Help?

Comment: did you install any gnome extension. Even they are not active?

Comment: Did not install any extensions. Gnome-tweaks lists Desktop icons, Ubuntu appindicator and Ubuntu dock in the Extensions page, but none are active.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but after a couple reboots the Show Applications area has suddenly started populating correctly. Can't fix something that's no longer broke, I guess. Hope this is the last bit of weirdness in 21.04.